# Narrator Doesn't Read the Contents of a Webview and the Contents of a Textblock on a UWP App

Tags: c#, uwp, accessibility, desktop-application, uwp-xaml

I have an app made with UWP, and when testing accessibility, I've noticed that Windows narrator couldn't read the text inside a Webview and the text inside Textblocks. Is there a known way to fix it? All the suggestions that I found, doesn't worked.

Comment: Test with [NVDA](https://www.nvaccess.org/download/) and [JAWS](https://support.freedomscientific.com/Downloads/JAWS) to make sure it's not a Narrator-only bug.

Comment: I've tried JAWS, but it still doesn't read text inside text blocks. Otherwise, JAWS reads the URL in the Webview (Windows Narrator doesn't even do that), but doesn't read the text .